# NDK r20 embedded toolchain fails on MacOS

Tags: macos, android, cmake

I am trying to build [libzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq) for Android using CMake and the toolchain embedded in the NDK.

My system is MacOS 10.14.3

I freshly downloaded the latest NDK [r20] but the problem was here already with r19c.

The CMake process fails when it tries to compile a "simple test program" and says:

```
ld: unknown option: --sysroot=/Users/me/android-ndk-r20/platforms/android-28/arch-arm
```

I tried to compile another library (custom) to confirm that its a toolchain issue and got the same error.

In the `--help`output of the compiler (from the embedded toolchain), I found this:

```
-isysroot <dir>         Set the system root directory (usually /)
```

Could there be an issue with the NDK toolchain for MacOS that passes the `--sysroot` parameter instead of the `-isysroot` one?
Is there a workaround? (Like something to add in the CMake toolchain file maybe?)

Here is my CMake toolchain file :

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 28) # API level
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI armeabi-v7a)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARM_MODE ON)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /Users/me/android-ndk-r20)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE c++_static)
```

In the meantime, I will run this through a Ubuntu docker image and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same exact issue on OSX and ended up reverting to the NDK 18b revision and it worked for my needs.

Same problem on the NDK Rev 19c. I think there's an issue with the NDK on r19c and r20

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up using a docker Ubuntu and cross-compiling using the CMake toolchain file from the Android NDK.
This way, I still use the latest NDK. I didn't post an answer because it does not really answer the question :S

Answer (score 0):

Toolchain needs to be specified:

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${HOME}/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
```

The Android Gradle Plugin invokes CMake with this argument which leads to no error. See [NDK's CMake page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake)